# async python - yield from raises AssertionError for correct parameters

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

My requirement is to run 2 functions at the same time and stop execution of one if the another one calculates and returns a result faster.

I have know knowledge of async programming or event loops. I read [python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#run-an-event-loop) which lead me to [asyncio.wait()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait)

My sample code:

```
import time
import asyncio as aio

async def f(x):
    time.sleep(1) # to fake fast work
    print("f say: " + str(x*2))
    return x*2

async def s(x):
    time.sleep(3) # to fake slow work
    print("s say: " + str(x*2))
    return x**2

x = 10

assert aio.iscoroutinefunction(f)
assert aio.iscoroutinefunction(s)

futures = {f(x), s(x)}

def executor():
    yield from aio.wait(futures, return_when=aio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

done, pending = executor()
```

But it doesnt work for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular assertion you are getting has to do with incorrect use of `yield from`. However, the problem runs deeper:

> My requirement is to run 2 functions at the same time

This is not how asyncio works, nothing is run "at the same time". Instead, one runs async functions which execute until the point when they reach what would normally be a blocking call. Instead of blocking, an async function then suspends its execution, allowing other coroutines to run. They must be driven by an *event loop*, which drives them and wakes them up once some IO event allows them to resume.

A more correct asyncio version of your code would look like this:

```
import asyncio

async def f(x):
    await asyncio.sleep(1) # to fake fast work
    print("f say: " + str(x*2))
    return x*2

async def s(x):
    await asyncio.sleep(3) # to fake slow work
    print("s say: " + str(x*2))
    return x**2

async def execute():
    futures = {f(10), s(10)}
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(futures, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    for fut in pending:
        fut.cancel()
    return done

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
done = loop.run_until_complete(execute())
print(done)
```

Note in particular that:

- `asyncio.sleep()` is used instead of `time.sleep()`. This applies to every blocking call.
- Coroutines such as `asyncio.sleep` and `asyncio.wait` must be *awaited* using the `await` keyword. This allows the coroutine to suspend itself upon encountering a blocking call.
- Async code is executed through the event loop, whose entry point is typically [`run_until_complete`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_until_complete) or [`run_forever`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_forever).

Comment: thanks for detail explaining. your second paragraph makes me think i should use threadpoolexecutor or something. am i on the right track?

Comment: @vvsLaxman If the functions are synchronous, then you can use `loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_function)`. Also note that Python's GIL will not allow functions to truly run at the same time.